# Select and format pasted article in word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have many occasions that I have to copy article from web-page, paste to word and format in a certain way. I had this code to auto paste and format. However, it only work once, and it just doesn't change the font of the pasted article later on.

```
Sub Macro1()

    Dim artic As Word.Range
    Set artic = Selection.Range
         'keep bold word bold and avoid paragraphs to cluster into one 
    artic.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatOriginalFormatting)
         'paste and select pasted article
    artic.Select
    artic.Font.Name = "Calibri"
    artic.Font.Size = 10.5
    artic.Font.Italic = False
    artic.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphLeft

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you explain what you want this macro to do each time you run it?

Comment: I would want the macro to paste an article with Paste Option:Keep Source Formatting, select the pasted article, format it to Calibri, size 10.5, not italic and align it to the left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set a breakpoint at `artic.Font.Name = "Calibri"` so that the code stops after `artic.Select` you'll see that the `Paste` method does *not* include what's been pasted. Generally, `artic` will be at the beginning of the pasted content.

This means the code needs to be able to locate the position just after where the Selection was before pasting. It also depends on whether the paste occurs at the end of the document, or not.

The following sample code worked for me in my tests. It uses two `Ranges`: one for where the content will be pasted, the other for the end position after pasting.

(Responding to request for more clarification about the Word object model): Think of a `Range` object like a selection, with the difference that there can be many Range objects, but only one Selection. When manipulating a `Range` it often helps to think of using the keyboard to reduce or expand it. Pressing the left- or right-arrow keys will "collapse" a selection to an insertion point; holding Shift and pressing these keys will expand/reduce a selection; holding Shift while clicking somewhere else in the document will also do that. Think of setting `Range.Start` or `Range.End` as the equivalent of this last. The start or end point of the Range is being arbitrarily set to another location in the document.

In the case of the first `If` in the code below the Range is being reduced/collapsed to its starting point (think left-arrow key), then moved one character to the right (think right-arrow key). This puts it beyond where new material will be pasted, so extending the paste point's end to this Range's starting point will pick up everything between the two.

```
Sub TestPasteAndSelect()
    Dim artic As Word.Range, rng As Word.Range
    Dim bNotAtEnd As Boolean

    Set artic = Selection.Range
    Set rng = artic.Duplicate
    rng.End = ActiveDocument.content.End
    If rng.Characters.Count > 1 Then
        'selection is not at end of document
        rng.Collapse wdCollapseStart
        rng.MoveStart wdCharacter, 1
        bNotAtEnd = True
    End If
         'keep bold word bold and avoid paragraphs to cluster into one
    artic.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatOriginalFormatting)
         'paste and select pasted article

    'artic.Select
    'rng.Select
    If bNotAtEnd Then
        artic.End = rng.Start
    Else
        Set artic = rng.Duplicate
    End If
    artic.Font.Name = "Calibri"
    artic.Font.Size = 10.5
    artic.Font.Italic = False
    artic.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphLeft
End Sub
```

Comment: I have a bit of background in Python but not much in vba. I can see you mean the code highlights the area where "the Selection" is going to be at before "the Selection" is placed. I am quite loss in the first loop. How do ".End" ,"rng.Collapse wdCollapseStart"  and "rng.MoveStart wdCharacter, 1" function?

Comment: @Marcoqwe123 I've expanded on the principle in the Answer. Is it clearer now?

Comment: The expansion has been very helpful to me in learning the concept! Much appreciated